# How to replace a spoke on a rim with no spoke holes?

Tags: wheels

Tubeless ready CX-R1 felt wheel. The spokes are sealed from the inside. How and what tools do I need to replace the spokes?

Comment: A photo would help here, I can't find any helpful images on Google, but it's almost certainly a threaded nipple. You thread them into the rim and onto the spoke at the same time.

Comment: Don't have the rim with me. Thanks for the comment. So the nipple threads one way and the spoke the other?

Comment: Yeah. This isn't uncommon for tubeless rims.

Comment: I can't seem to find a tutorial or explanation anywhere. Have you seen one?

Comment: The only thing I can find is this Easton video. Other manufacturers may have a slightly different procedure. Worth a look though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAdO33oLvn0

Comment: My fulcrums involve a magnet and a whole lot of fiddling about, but as others have said its manufacturer dependent.

Comment: Seems like rim tape is a better option than omitting spoke holes.

Comment: Vote to leave open - the question is pretty clearly "how to replace a spoke on a cx-r1 felt wheel which has no spoke holes?  And what tools will be needed"

Comment: Are you positive that there's not simply a rubber rim strip inside the rim?  Even the funny Easton rims I worked on recently had this.

Comment: No it's sealed, it's common on tubeless wheels.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It looks like a pretty standard threaded nipple with aluminum spokes. Is the spoke broken off right at/in the nipple, by the rim, or is there enough of the broken spoke sticking out of the nipple that you can 'grap' it with a pliers/vice-grip type tool? ...

a). If the spoke broke off right at the nipple, leaving nothing to grasp -- or if the nipple itself is somehow damaged -- then you'll need to remove the rim strip/rim tape from the inside of the rim in order to remove the nipple. Spoke nipples aren't threaded into the rim so it should 'back out'/fall out freely. In this case, you will need a **spoke wrench** to install the new spoke and you will need to install **new rim tape** after the new spoke and nipple are installed. You may need an **sharp knife** to carefully cut/lift the old rim tape.  Otherwise...

b). If you can grab the broken spoke securely, just use a spoke wrench to turn the nipple and un-thread the broken spoke. You shouldn't need to access the nipple from the 'inside' of the rim. In this case, you will need a **spoke wrench** (to turn the nipple) and a **pliers** (to grasp onto the broken spoke).

Comment: On the Eastons I worked on recently the rim strip was fairly stretchy rubber and could be removed without apparent damage.

Comment: Thanks but they were the sealed kind. No rim tape or holes on the inside. Magnet was required to guide the nipples.